# Sql join in the same tabel

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have sql tabel

```
ikey     Date            iDiverkey     Status 
----    ------           ---------     -------
1     27/02/2017 15:26     1156          1   
2     27/02/2017 17:26     1156          2

Note 1 ---> Trip Start
     2 ---> Trip stop
```

I need Output as

```
Date           iDiverKey       Start      Stop
27/022017        1156          15:26      17:26
```

please help me to get the output

Comment: Is this data set properly representative of the problem?

Comment: Will you have Two different date for single iDiverkey ?? like start on today night and stop on tomorrow morning ??

Comment: no, it may be having same date as well as different dates also

Comment: so which date will come there in the output ?? start date or end date ??

Comment: start only date have to come

Comment: The case for  group by

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want is the first start date (status 1 I presume) and last end date (status 2 I presume) for each date for each iDriverkey, then something like this:-

```
SELECT DATE(`Date`), 
        iDriverkey,
        MIN(IF(Status = 1, TIME(`Date`), NULL)) AS `Start`,
        MAX(IF(Status = 2, TIME(`Date`), NULL)) AS `Stop`
FROM somedatatable
GROUP BY DATE(`Date`), 
        iDriverkey
```